# Disable mouse events

Tags: powershell

During script execution, I need to disable (or enable) mouse events, depending on the task ($React = $False or $True). I do it like this:

```
$React = $False (or $True, depending on the task)

$Element01.Add_MouseLeave({ if ( $React ) { Do something 01 } })   
$Element01.Add_MouseEnter({ if ( $React ) { Do something 02 } })

$Element02.Add_MouseLeave({ if ( $React ) { Do something 03 } })   
$Element02.Add_MouseHover({ if ( $React ) { Do something 04 } })
```

Is there a better way to enable or disable all mouse events (Enter, Click, Hover, Up, Down, Move and more) or specific events, for example, only all MouseEnter?

I do not want to use .Enabled, as in this case the visual display of form elements, for example, such as text, is disrupted:

```
# Not suitable

$Element01.Enabled = $False
$Element02.Enabled = $False
```

I want to know a similar opportunity (if any), as described below.

```
$Form.DisableEventMouse() # That would be perfect
```

or

```
# The first case
# Disable all mouse events using which $Something

$Something = $False

$Element01.Add_MouseLeave({ Do something 01 }) # The event is not executing
$Element01.Add_MouseEnter({ Do something 02 }) # The event is not executing

$Element02.Add_MouseLeave({ Do something 03 }) # The event is not executing
$Element02.Add_MouseHover({ Do something 04 }) # The event is not executing

# The second case
# Enable all mouse events using which $Something

$Something = $True

$Element01.Add_MouseLeave({ Do something 01 }) # The event is executing
$Element01.Add_MouseEnter({ Do something 02 }) # The event is executing

$Element02.Add_MouseLeave({ Do something 03 }) # The event is executing
$Element02.Add_MouseHover({ Do something 04 }) # The event is executing
```

Many thanks

Comment: Why do you need to disable these events?

Comment: I need that under certain conditions the user should not be able to receive mouse events.  ".Enabled" is not suitable, as it changes the appearance of the form.  I want the appearance to remain unchanged, but the ability to make a mouseover event is disabled.